# Determine a thread's stack size and location

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack, radix

how can I determine the base of a thread's stack and its size under Linux? Is there an available C/C++ API or a way to find out in gdb?
thanks

Comment: What language? C/C++? Something else?

Comment: Use frame 0 to get the most inner frame, then up and up?

Comment: Why do you want to find that thru an API? What for? You could store inside TLS or global data the address of some starting local variable in each thread ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You mean I should allocate a stack variable right after each thread starts and find out its address? This should be approximately fine, I was thinking that there exists a cleaner approach, smoewhere the stack base ptr needs to be stored..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different method of doing this, involving reading `/proc/self/maps`. Unlike some of the other methods, it doesn't require special instrumentation at the start of your program and gives you an *exact* position for the end of the stack.

If you try `cat /proc/self/maps`, you get something like this:

```
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6039736              /usr/bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 6039736              /usr/bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 6039736              /usr/bin/cat
00908000-00929000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                    [heap]
7fcdb1c68000-7fcdb1e01000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6032628      /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fcdb1e01000-7fcdb2000000 ---p 00199000 08:01 6032628      /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fcdb2000000-7fcdb2004000 r--p 00198000 08:01 6032628      /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fcdb2004000-7fcdb2006000 rw-p 0019c000 08:01 6032628      /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fcdb2006000-7fcdb200a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcdb200a000-7fcdb202c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6032717      /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fcdb21f5000-7fcdb21f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcdb2209000-7fcdb222b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcdb222b000-7fcdb222c000 r--p 00021000 08:01 6032717      /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fcdb222c000-7fcdb222d000 rw-p 00022000 08:01 6032717      /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fcdb222d000-7fcdb222e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffe78c41000-7ffe78c62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0            [stack]
7ffe78dba000-7ffe78dbc000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0            [vvar]
7ffe78dbc000-7ffe78dbe000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0            [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0    [vsyscall]
```

As you can see, there is a `[stack]` entry. This is probably what you're looking for.

An example program to parse this line out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    char line[1024];
    void *result = NULL;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line) / sizeof(char), file) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        unsigned long start, end, offset;
        unsigned int devma, devmi, ino;
        char perms[6];
        char path[128];
        if (sscanf(line, "%lx-%lx %5s %lx %d:%d %d %127s", &start, &end, &perms, &offset, &devma, &devmi, &ino, &path) != 8) {
            continue; // could not parse. fail gracefully and try again on the next line.
        }
        if (strcmp(path, "[stack]") == 0) { // use [stack:TID] for a thread besides the main thread
            printf("Stack found from %lx to %lx\n", start, end);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print something like:

```
Stack found from 7fff91834000 to 7fff91855000
```

This is probably fairly close to what you're looking for.

Comment: this is how I ended up doing it. If you have multiple threads and need to find the stack for a particular thread, you can use the address of any stack variable and match it against the stack ranges.

Comment: Yeah - you can also just use `gettid()` and `[stack:TID]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with not getting the exact top of the stack (which might be enough for some applications), traversing the frame pointers could work:

```
// main.c
#include <stdint.h>

// -fno-omit-frame-pointer might be required - otherwise you might get a crash
// might not be exactly at the top; but probably very close

void *stack_top() {
    void **top;
    asm("movq %%rbp, %0" : "=r" (top)); // set top to %rbp - replace with %ebp for 32-bit x86
    // if top is higher in memory than the variable, then still part of the stack.
    while ((uintptr_t) *top > (uintptr_t) &top) {
        top = *top;
    }
    return top;
}
```

This works because the `%rbp` register (or `%ebp` register on 32-bit) is used to store the pointer to the base of the parent stack frame (where the saved `%rbp` or `%ebp` value is) - so we can iteratively traverse this linked list until we reach an invalid address.

Note that `stack_top` might fail in some cases relating to the `&top` comparison - my system terminated the linked list with a pointer to a location in the program loading code, so this was the best way that I found to detect this - but you'll want to test this thoroughly. (If anyone has a better way to detect the end of the chain, please add a comment.)

Example test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *test_another_layer(int x) {
    return stack_top();
}

void *subthread(void *ptr) {
    void *st1 = stack_top();
    void *st2 = test_another_layer(0);
    void *st3 = &ptr;
    printf("stack tops 2: %x %x %x\n", st1, st2, st3);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *st1 = stack_top();
    void *st2 = test_another_layer(0);
    void *st3 = &argc;
    printf("stack tops: %x %x %x\n", st1, st2, st3);
    pthread_t ot;
    if (pthread_create(&ot, NULL, subthread, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("cannot create");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pthread_join(ot, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("cannot join");
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```